# Error executing Go file : file does not exist

Tags: go

I've two GO files from [this](https://github.com/google/omaha/tree/master/common/certificate_tag) Google GitHub repo:

1. certificate_tag.go
2. certificate_tag_test.go

I've cloned the repo so my directory structure where all relevant files are present is exactly same:

[image]

Now I run below commands in [this](https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag_test.go) file one by one to execute it :

```
go build -o C:/tmp/certificate_tag common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag.go
```

This creates a file at `C:/tmp/certificate_tag` as shown below:

[image]

But now when I run below command it results in error:

```
go test common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag_test.go common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag.go -tag-binary-dir "C:/tmp"
```

Error text is as below:

> $ go test common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag_test.go
> common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag.go -tag-binary-dir "C:/tmp"
> --- FAIL: TestPrintAppendedTag (0.00s)
> certificate_tag_test.go:74: Error executing "C:\tmp\certificate_tag": exec: "C:\tmp\certificate_tag": file
> does not exist; output:
> --- FAIL: TestSetSuperfluousCertTag (0.01s)
> certificate_tag_test.go:101: Test input testdata\ChromeSetup.exe, error executing "C:\tmp\certificate_tag": exec:
> "C:\tmp\certificate_tag": file does not exist; output: FAIL FAIL
> command-line-arguments  4.640s FAIL

Code for `TestPrintAppendedTag`  is as below:

```
func TestPrintAppendedTag(t *testing.T) {
    cmd := exec.Command(tagBinary, "--dump-appended-tag", sourceExe)
    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error executing %q: %v; output:\n%s", tagBinary, err, output)
    }

    if out := string(output); !strings.Contains(out, existingTagSubstring) {
        t.Errorf("Output of --dump-appended-tag didn't contain %s, as expected. Got:\n%s", existingTagSubstring, out)
    }
}
```

Why it is unable to find the file which was created at `C:/tmp/certificate_tag` in step 1 above even when it is there?

**Update**: As suggested by Volker and Chen, now I'm running below command:

```
go test -run TestPrintAppendedTag
```

It is giving below error:

> certificate_tag_test.go:75: Error executing "\tmp\certificate_tag":
> exec: "\tmp\certificate_tag": file does not exist;

Comment: Neither `go build` nor `go test` work well with **filename** arguments. Use no arguments whatsoever and follow https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started

Comment: These commands were present in [this](https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag_test.go) GitHub repository from Google only. Please see line number 40 in this file.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Sometimes Google engineers do make mistakes.

Comment: I tried running `go test` command as you suggested but it is giving new error. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

When running go tests, you don't need to specify the `.go` file of the test, simply run `go test -run` to run all tests in current directory. If you want something more specific, you need to specify the test names, rather than files.

```golang
go test              # Run all tests.
go test -run Foo     # Run top-level tests matching "Foo", such as "TestFooBar".
go test -run Foo/A=  # For top-level tests matching "Foo", run subtests matching "A=".
go test -run /A=1    # For all top-level tests, run subtests matching "A=1".
```

Check out the [testing](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) package docs and other [examples](https://blog.golang.org/examples) from the go blog.

Comment: when I run `go test` it giver error - `package run is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\run)
`

Comment: In your updated question, the error you get is a path problem. You should fix the path to the file you're trying to access

Comment: I'm not sure why it is crying for `tmp\certificate_tag`. I don't see any mention of it in the `TestPrintAppendedTag` function. Full source code of the two files I'm using is available here on GitHub. I'm trying to make use of [this](https://github.com/google/omaha/tree/master/common/certificate_tag) repo from Google.

Comment: https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/common/certificate_tag/certificate_tag_test.go#L74 above this line you can see a command is being executed.